# How to infer about the subspace from its span - linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

> The following subspaces are given in $\Bbb R^3$:
>
> $W=\text{span}\{(1,2,-1),(0,1,1),(2,5,-1)\}$
>
> $U=\text{span}\{(-2,-6,0),(1,1,-2)\}$
>
> Is $W=U$?

I noticed that: $2(1,2,-1)+(0,1,1)=(2,5,-1) \Rightarrow W=sp\{(1,2,-1),(0,1,1)\} $

Also that: $U=sp\{(-2,-6,0),(1,1,-2)  \}=sp\{(1,3,0),(1,1,-2)\}$

And: $(1,3,0)+(1,1,-2)=(2,4,-2)=(1,2,-1)$ which is the first vector of $spW$.

And: $(1,2,-1)+(0,1,1)=(1,3,0)$ which is the first vector of $spU$.

But from here I'm not really sure how to write a deduction about U and W.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(1,2,-1)+(0,1,1)=(1,3,0)$ and $(1,2,-1)+(-1)(0,1,1)=(1,1,-2)$

Comment: @Gigili I checked and both  $spW$ and $spU$ are linear combinations of each other, but does that tell me that U=W ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need to show that every vector in either set is a linear combination of vectors in the other set.

For the simplified subspaces you calculated:

$$W=\text{span}\{(1,2,-1),(0,1,1)\}$$

$$U=\text{span}\{(1,3,0),(1,1,-2)\}$$

We have:

$(1,2,-1)+(0,1,1)=(1,3,0)$ and $(1,2,-1)+(-1)(0,1,1)=(1,1,-2)$

So they're equal.

---

Another way of showing that two subspaces of same dimension are equal is computing their normal vectors:

$
N_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
i&j&k\\
1&2&-2\\
0&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

From there we have $N_1=3i+j+k$.

$
N_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
i&j&k\\
1&3&0\\
1&1&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
Then $N_2$ would be $-6i-2j-2k$.

The two normal vectors are multiple of each other, therefore the two subspaces are equal. $\blacksquare$